# How do I get the time spent for a particular agent (from MHL) at a particular node?

Tags: anylogic

I am interested in capturing the time a particular material handler(AGV in my case) spends at a particular node before it is released. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

This works in general, since I don't know anything about your model (there are many other ways depending on what you are doing):

Create a variable and make it equal to time when your AGV arrives to the node:

```
timeWhenArrivesToNode=time();
```

Create another variable and make it equal to the amount of time it spent in that node... This code should be executed at the moment when the AGV leaves the node:

```
timesWhenItIsReleased=time()-timeWhenArrivesToNode;
```

Of course the answer will have the time units of your model.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, Felipe.

What other information would you need for my model? The AGVs in the model are used to transport boxes to a particular station. So, before being accepted by the station, the previous boxes there have to be completed first. In this case, the AGV will wait at the station for it to open up again.

Here I want to study the time the AGV spends waiting before the station opens up. Regarding your solution, for  'timeWhenArrivesToNode=time()' as a variable, how does it know which node I am referring to?

Thanks